# Flutter - How can I update a List<Map>

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary

How can I upate the following List of Map:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> entries = [
   {
      'name1': 'John',
      'age1': 21
   },
   {
      'name2': 'Paul',
      'age2': 18 
   }
]
```

I tried to use

```
entries.update({'name2': 'Frank', 'age2': 28});
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the index.

Then Try This:

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> entries = [
    {'name1': 'John', 'age1': 21},
    {'name2': 'Paul', 'age2': 18}
  ];

  void updateMap() {
    print(entries[1]['name2']);
    entries[1] = {'name2': 'Usman', 'age2': 88};
    print(entries[1]['name2']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> entries =[];
entries[index] ={'name2': 'Frank', 'age2': 28};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
entries[1] = {'name2': 'Frank', 'age2': 28};
```